# Density of prime numbers:

Tags: python

I'm supposed to write a function which gets two integers, the function caculates the density of prime numbers with n bits long, by getting random (times) integers with n bits long, and finds how many of them are prime, the output would be (cntprimes/times).
I've written my code but I get an error with the import random.
NameError: global name 'random' is not defined.
Please, let me know what I should fix in my code.

```
def is_prime(m):
""" probabilistic test for compositeness of m>30
adds a trivial sieve to quickly eliminate divisibility
by small primes. """
if m in [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]:
    return True    # treats small primes separately
for prime in [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]:
    if m % prime == 0:
        return False
for i in range(0,100):
    a = random.randint(1,m-1) # a is a random integer in [1..m-1]
    if pow(a,m-1,m) != 1:
            return False
return True



def density_primes(n, times=10000):            
    from random import getrandbits
    cntprimes=0
    for i in range(times):
        global num
        num=random.getrandbits(n)

        if is_prime(num):
            cntprimes+=1

    density=cntprimes/times
    return(density)
```

Comment: You need to `import random` at the top

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
from random import getrandbits
cntprimes=0
for i in range(times):
    global num
    num=random.getrandbits(n)
```

You can do:

```
import random          # bring 'random' into the current namespace
random.getrandbits(n)  # use it
```

or you can do:

```
from random import getrandbits    # bring 'getrandbits' into the current namespace
getrandbits(n)                    # use it
```

but you can't mix them and do this:

```
from random import getrandbits    # bring 'getrandbits' in
random.getrandbits(n)             # try to use random, without bringing it in
```

Which is what your code does.